# Create bitmap font using C#

Tags: c#, fonts

I have list of bitmaps (for each letter) and i have to create font using those bitmaps.
I know ttf format is very very complicated to create, so i want to create fon file (raster bitmap font).
I understand it can be created by create a dll and rename it from *.dll to *.fon, or something similiar.
No code sample or any knonledge about it in the web!!!!
Can you help me??? it should be C# code.
Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: where did you hear that?

Comment: You mean the dll renaming? i find it somewhere, not sure where exactly (and not sure it is correct..)
Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Yea, .fon files are apparently indeed renamed Windows resource (exe/dll) files with no code but only resources inside it. Weird system...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sibcode.com/font-editor/index.htm

That font editor support what you need